# imgur image not loading due to CORS policy

Tags: bug, stack-snippets, imgur

I am facing a very annoying issue that seems to happen only in a very particular case. When I use a transparent image hosted in imgur inide the `mask` property, it doesn't load.

Here is the concerned [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47829344/8620333) where I uploaded the image elsewhere and it works fine. If you check the deleted answer below, you will see the same code with the same image uploaded on imgur. It won't work and I am getting the following message:

> [image]

The strange part is that the image works fine if it's added inside the answer or within `img` or  `background-image`. You can clearly see this in the deleted answer.

It's also the same on meta.

Here is the non working version:

```css
.img-poster {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  -webkit-mask:  
     linear-gradient(#fff,#fff)              top,
     url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmylJ.png) bottom;
  -webkit-mask-size:
     100% calc(100% - 30px),
     auto 30px;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: repeat-x;
  mask:  
     linear-gradient(#fff,#fff)              top,
     url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmylJ.png) bottom;
  mask-size:
     100% calc(100% - 30px),
     auto 30px;
  mask-repeat: repeat-x;
}

img {
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<section class="section poster-container">
  <img src="https://imagejournal.org/wp-content/uploads/bb-plugin/cache/23466317216_b99485ba14_o-panorama.jpg" alt="" class="img-poster add img-responsive">
</section>
```

And the working one:

```css
.img-poster {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  -webkit-mask:  
     linear-gradient(#fff,#fff)              top,
     url(https://i.ibb.co/5WvbqgG/zmylJ.png) bottom;
  -webkit-mask-size:
     100% calc(100% - 30px),
     auto 30px;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: repeat-x;
  mask:  
     linear-gradient(#fff,#fff)              top,
     url(https://i.ibb.co/5WvbqgG/zmylJ.png) bottom;
  mask-size:
     100% calc(100% - 30px),
     auto 30px;
  mask-repeat: repeat-x;
}

img {
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<section class="section poster-container">
  <img src="https://imagejournal.org/wp-content/uploads/bb-plugin/cache/23466317216_b99485ba14_o-panorama.jpg" alt="" class="img-poster add img-responsive">
</section>
```

The result should be the following:

> [image]

---

I am using Windows 10 (64bit) and the last version of Chrome (80.0.3987.122 (64 bits)). The same happen on Firefox too but it seems to work fine on Edge.

Comment: Both images are loading for me

Comment: @SterlingArcher you see the same result in both snippet? check the bottom part

Comment: Ah excuse me, you're right. Sorry about that

Comment: https://drafts.fxtf.org/css-masking-1/#priv-sec